How does the expression of $x_t$ and $y_t$ coming?
Consider a simple, smooth, closed initial curve $\gamma(0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $\gamma(t)$ be the one-parameter family of curves, where $t \in [0, \infty)$ is time, generated by moving the initial curve along its normal vector field with speed $F$, a given function of the curvature. Let $\vec{x}(s, t)$ be the position vector which, at time $t$, parameterizes $\gamma(t)$ by $s$, $0 \leq s \leq S$, $\vec{x}(0, t) = \vec{x}(S, t)$. We assume the curve is parameterized so that the interior is on the left as we travel along the curve in the direction of increasing $s$.
With $\kappa(s, t)$ as the curvature at $\vec{x}(s, t)$, the equations of motion are:
$$\vec{n}(s, t) \cdot \frac{\partial \vec{x}(s, t)}{\partial t} = F(\kappa(s, t))$$
$$\vec{x}(s, 0) = \gamma(0), \quad s \in [0, S], \quad t \in [0, \infty)$$
where $\vec{n}(s, t)$ is the unit normal vector at $\vec{x}(s, t)$.
Written in terms of the coordinates $\vec{x}(s, t) = (x(s, t), y(s, t))$, an equivalent formulation is:
$$x_t = F\left(\frac{y_{ss}x_s - x_{ss}y_s}{(x_s^2 + y_s^2)^{3/2}}\right) y_s$$
$$y_t = -F\left(\frac{y_{ss}x_s - x_{ss}y_s}{(x_s^2 + y_s^2)^{3/2}}\right) x_s$$
with:
$$(x(s, 0), y(s, 0)) = \gamma(0), \quad 0 \leq s \leq S.$$
My attempt:-
$$\vec{n}(s, t) \cdot \frac{\partial \vec{x}(s, t)}{\partial t} = F(\kappa(s, t))$$
$$(\vec{n}(s, t) \cdot \frac{\partial \vec{x}(s, t)}{\partial t})\vec{n}(s, t) = F(\kappa(s, t))\vec{n}(s, t)$$
Along the normal direction, we have
$$(\vec{n}(s, t) \cdot (x_t(s, t), y_t(s,t))\vec{n}(s, t) = F(\kappa(s, t))\vec{n}(s, t)$$
We know that unit tangent vector is $\vec{t}(s, t)=\frac{(x_s(s, t), y_s(s,t))}{\sqrt{x_s(s, t)^2+y_s(s,t)^2}}$ and  $\vec{n}(s, t)=\frac{(y_s(s, t), -x_s(s,t))}{\sqrt{x_s(s, t)^2+y_s(s,t)^2}}.$
I know $\kappa(s,t)=\frac{y_{ss}x_s - x_{ss}y_s}{(x_s^2 + y_s^2)^{3/2}}$
$$(\frac{(y_s(s, t), -x_s(s,t))}{\sqrt{x_s(s, t)^2+y_s(s,t)^2}} \cdot (x_t(s, t), y_t(s,t))\frac{(y_s(s, t), -x_s(s,t))}{\sqrt{x_s(s, t)^2+y_s(s,t)^2}} = F(\frac{y_{ss}(s,t)x_s(s,t) - x_{ss}(s,t)y_s(s,t)}{(x_s^2(s,t) + y_s^2(s,t))^{3/2}})\frac{(y_s(s, t), -x_s(s,t))}{\sqrt{x_s(s, t)^2+y_s(s,t)^2}}$$
$$ (y_s\frac{(y_sx_t -y_t x_s)}{\sqrt{x_s^2+y_s^2}}, -x_s\frac{(y_sx_t -y_t x_s)}{\sqrt{x_s^2+y_s^2}}) = F(\frac{y_{ss}x_s - x_{ss}y_s}{(x_s^2 + y_s^2)^{3/2}})(y_s, -x_s)$$
$$ (\frac{(y_s^2x_t -y_t y_s x_s)}{\sqrt{x_s^2+y_s^2}}, \frac{(-x_s y_sx_t +y_t x_s^2)}{\sqrt{x_s^2+y_s^2}}) = (F(\frac{y_{ss}x_s - x_{ss}y_s}{(x_s^2 + y_s^2)^{3/2}})y_s, -F(\frac{y_{ss}x_s - x_{ss}y_s}{(x_s^2 + y_s^2)^{3/2}})x_s)$$
I don't know how do they arrive the expressions for $x_t$ and $y_t$. It was from the following paper https://math.berkeley.edu/~sethian/Papers/sethian.comm_math.85.pdf
Please help me.

Why are you taking dot products? Write out the vector equation.

How to simplify this $(\vec{n}(s, t) \cdot \frac{\partial \vec{x}(s, t)}{\partial t})\vec{n}(s, t)$?

I spoke too quickly. I think there are two problems here. The first is that you did not correctly quote the result from the paper. On the right-hand side you should have the components of the unit normal, so $y_s/\sqrt{x_s^2+y_s^2}$, etc. The second is that the author was sloppy. The evolution equation is misstated, and he's using $\dfrac{\partial\vec x}{\partial t} = F(\kappa)\vec n$, not what he wrote. Indeed, the dot product equation makes the evolution not at all well-defined.
